# Lint fails the build with Security error "WrongConstant: Incorrect constant". IntDef annotation

Tags: android, gradle, annotations, lint

In my `Result` class I annotated with [@IntDef](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html) first integer parameter in `newInstance()` method like this:

```
public class Result {
    public static final int SUCCESS = 0;
    public static final int FAIL = 1;
    public static final int UNKNOWN = 2;

    // ...

    private Result(@Status int status, Uri uri) {
        mStatus = status;
        mUri = uri;
    }

    public static Result newInstance(@Status int status, Uri uri) {
        return new Result(status, uri);
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @IntDef({ SUCCESS, FAIL, UNKNOWN })
    @interface Status {}
}
```

Next, in my `Utils` class I invoke that method and pass correct constant as parameter. I ensure that I use specific set of constants like this:

```
public static Result foo() {
    // ...
    return Result.newInstance(Result.SUCCESS, contentUri); // line 45
}
```

But lint fails the build with Security error

> **"WrongConstant: Incorrect constant"**
>
> ../../src/main/java/my/package/Utils.java:45: Must be one of: 0, 1, 2

I know that this error can be simply suppressed. But I'd like to know what's wrong with my code? Or maybe it's another issue?

Comment: Very strange, I even don't find such lint warning definition

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue with a `@StringDef` constant. I guess this particular Lint check has some issues.

In the meantime, you can use the `@SuppressLint` annotation as a workaround:

```
public static Result foo() {
    // ...
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    return Result.newInstance(Result.SUCCESS, contentUri);
}
```

---

*Edit:* This issue seems to be fixed with gradle plugin version 1.4.0-beta1
[Issue 182179 - android - Lint gives erroneous @StringDef errors in androidTests](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182179)

Answer (score -1):

Like the error says, the value must be 0,1,2.

[Result.SUCCESS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK) has a value of -1

Comment: No, _Result.SUCCESS_ is the constant declared in my own class. It's definitely equal to 0. You've posted the link to Activity.RESULT_OK which is out of scope.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an import that uses a different Result?